# PHP remove the common elements between two Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$B = array(4,5,9,10);
```

Expecting Output:

```
$C = array(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Want to remove the common elements between the arrays.

Comment: Read about [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: Consider reading the PHP Docs.... `$C = array_merge(array_diff($A, $B), array_diff($B, $A));`

Comment: Or `$C = array_diff(array_merge($A, $B), array_intersect($A, $B));`

Answer (score 1):

first, you get one array that contains all elements, then one that contains intersecting elements.
then you remove the intersecting from all

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$B = array(4,5,9,10);
$combined = array_merge($A,$B);
$intersect =array_intersect($A, $B);
var_dump(array_diff($combined, $intersect));
```

giving you

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [5]=>
  int(6)
  [6]=>
  int(7)
  [7]=>
  int(8)
  [10]=>
  int(9)
  [11]=>
  int(10)
}
```